# My C# function causes Unity to freeze on play

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I press play in Unity it freezes (the majority of the time. Only very few times it works)

This is the function that seems to be the problem:

```
    void SeperateCells() {
        // Seems to already crash here.
        bool cellCollision = true;
        int loop = 0;
        while (cellCollision) {
            loop++;
            cellCollision = false;
            if (debug) {
                Debug.Log("Loop " + loop);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < cells.Count; i++) {
                GenCell c = cells[i];
                for (int j = i + 1; j < cells.Count; j++) {
                    GenCell cb = cells[j];
                    if (c.CollidesWith(cb)) {
                        cellCollision = true;

                        int cb_x = Mathf.RoundToInt((c.x + c.width) - cb.x);
                        int c_x = Mathf.RoundToInt((cb.x + cb.width) - c.x);
                        int cb_y = Mathf.RoundToInt((c.y + c.height) - cb.y);
                        int c_y = Mathf.RoundToInt((cb.y + cb.height) - c.y);

                        if (c_x < cb_x) {
                            if (c_x < c_y) {
                                c.Shift(c_x, 0);
                            }
                            else {
                                c.Shift(0, c_y);
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            if (cb_x < cb_y) {
                                cb.Shift(cb_x, 0);
                            }
                            else {
                                cb.Shift(0, cb_y);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Some times it goes through and does what it's supposed to.

Comment: Probably an infinite loop where you constantly set `cellCollision = true`, only you can debug this I'm afraid.

Comment: But why does it sometimes work and others not?

Comment: I have no idea, I don't know what your code does as it references things outside of this method that you don't explain. Also, I don't really want to go through this long function. You should debug this yourself and see what is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're problem is here

```
while (cellCollision) {
        loop++;
        cellCollision = false;
```

and here

```
if (c.CollidesWith(cb)) {
        cellCollision = true;
```

Basically, what is happening here when it first goes through the while loop, it only needs to do it once because `cellCollision` is made false after it goes through once so it doesn't need to loop again. Then, once `c.CollidesWith(cb)` becomes true, it makes `cellCollision` true again causing it to go through the loop again. Unless you have a way to change `c.CollidesWith(cb)` to false, it is going to become and infinite loop so you need to make `c.CollidesWith(cb)` false again or use another boolean to prevent this infinite loop.

Comment: That's what the `Shift` calls are for, but it appears that no resolution for one object being pushed off one object and onto another is not being handled correctly.

Comment: Thanks that was it!